# AngularJS : get select label without modifying ng-model

Tags: javascript, angularjs, enums

I'm currently stuck with a problem which seems simple :

Controller :

```
$scope.fruits = [{
    name: 'AP',
    label: 'Apple'
  }, {
    name: 'BA',
    label: 'Bananas'
  }];
```

HTML code :

```
<select
    ng-model="meal.fruit"
    ng-options="fruit.name as fruit.label for fruit in fruits">
</select>

<p>Fruit : {{meal.fruit}}</p>
```

Problem is, this displays

```
Fruit : BA
```

Instead of

```
Fruit : Bananas
```

I can't modify ng-option to "fruit as fruit.label" because I need my model "meal.fruit" to be "AP" or "BA" (because it is a java enum deserialize by Jackson, and it requires the Enum value).

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2qfSB/71/)

In summary, I need meal.fruit to be "BA" and I also want to be able to display the selected value "Bananas" somewhere else.

What can I do ?

EDIT :

The solution that worked for me was found by [Maxim Shoustin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1631379/maxim-shoustin), (many thanks !) :

I modified my code to have the following :

http://jsfiddle.net/2qfSB/77/

And then I modified my submit method to add the following :

```
$scope.meal.fruit = $scope.meal.fruit.name;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just change `ng-options`:

```
ng-options="fruit.label as fruit.label for fruit in fruits">
```

Fixed Demo: <kbd>**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2qfSB/74/)**</kbd>

*as a side note*

You can set by default 1st element to avoid empty combo by using `ng-init`:

```
<select
        ng-model="meal.fruit"
        ng-options="fruit.label as fruit.label for fruit in fruits"
        ng-init="meal.fruit = fruits[0].label"
    >
```

Demo: <kbd>**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2qfSB/75/)**</kbd>

Comment: That doesn't fix my problem, because now meal.fruit contains "Bananas" when I submit my form. I need it to contain "BA" to be deserialized by Jackson :(

Comment: from your example `<p>Fruit : {{meal.fruit}}</p>`. And you wanted: `Fruit : Bananas`. So I lost you, can you give more info?

Comment: I know, this part is now good, but i need meal.fruit to be "BA" to be deserialized by Jackson

Comment: With your solution, when I submit my form I have this kind of error : org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: No enum const class mypackages.Fruits.Banana

Comment: So you want to display in Web Bananas but meal.fruit should be enum BA, right?

Comment: Exactly, that's it ! :)

Comment: This time, what is sent is not {{fruit.name|json}} but {{fruit|json}} which (unfortunately), Jackson can't map to my enum : Can not deserialize instance of mypakcages.enum.fruit out of START_OBJECT token

Comment: Why you can't send `fruit.name`? Please post `form send` method

Comment: Riiiiiiiiight !! By modifying the submit method by adding this : "$scope.meal.fruit = $scope.meal.fruit.name;" it works just fine ! Thanks you very much :)